# Is there any rules to maven RELEASE or SNAPSHOT version numbers?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I had a general query about maven versioning numbers. Are there some specific rules to giving version numbers to SNAPSHOT or RELEASE for a maven based project?
E.g. we have multiple rules for variable naming like we cannot start with a digit. Likewise, do we have any such specific rules violating which does not allow the artifact gets published?
I came across such a situation where I provided version number like **X.YY-SNAPSHOT(say 2.56-SNAPSHOT)** and it failed to publish properly. When I changed that to **X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT**, it worked fine. I tried to find information related to this but couldn't hit any properly.

Please enlight me here.

Comment: What do you mean by `(say 2.56-SNAPSHOT) and it failed to publish properly.` and where have you published? The `-SNAPSHOT` is a versions which is towards a release ˚ 2.56` so SNAPSHOT means under development not ready yet. A release is a fixed state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, technically, you can use any combination of numbers, dots, hyphens and letters as a version number. Something like `2.56-SNAPSHOT` is totally fine.

Of course, some organisations might introduce further restrictions, e.g. that a version number has to have the form `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` but this is not a Maven thing.